# How to retrieve activities from Garmin Fenix3

Tags: android, garmin

I'd like to automatically import my activities from my Garmin Fenix3 into a database (without the need to manually download the TCX files). Two options came to my mind to solve this task:

1. A Server based app which gets connected to the Garmin Connect API and is notified (via RESTful APIs) by GarminConnect each time an activity has been uploaded - is my understanding correct, that I need for this use case the $5,000 expensive Garmin API licence?? http://developer.garmin.com/garmin-connect-api/overview/
2. Create an Android App which gets notified by the installed Garmin Android Connect App each time a new activity has been created - how can I achieve this? From my understanding, the Connect IQ Mobile SDK For Android can be used to create an Android App which interacts with your own application on the Garmin Device itself (which is not needed for my scenario, I just want to automatically "download" the activities created by the default Fenix3 apps).

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for you, but just a note on your first point: while Connect API isn't free, one way to circumvent this would be to create a Strava account and authorize it to read Garmin. Strava can automatically sync all your activities and they have a free API: http://labs.strava.com/developers/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can answer now my own question. It is NOT possible to access the recorded data automatically unless you pay the $5,000 for the Garmin API licence (this is soooo ridiculous Garmin!!!). The Connect IQ Mobile SDK approach will NOT do this job, confirmed by the Garmin Support Team.

The only way to get your data is by manually downloading the FIT or TCX file from https://connect.garmin.com . Keep in mind though that the Running Dynamics (which are captured and calculated by the HRM-Run sensor) are NOT included in these files!

- Vertical Oscillation
- Vertical Ratio
- Left/Right Balance
- Avg Ground Contact Time
- Training Effect

This is a very big disappointment Garmin! In which century are you guys still living? The data generated by the user belongs to the user and it should be easy accessible! Keeping the data locked in your safe will not really attract more users to the connect platform... But time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

This one is old, so worth mentioning that you can now request access to Garmin API via their website. Once you are approved you are good to access your data via API.